# Rails / Formtastic - Validation isn't occuring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, formtastic

I'm using formtastic to validate forms:

```
<%= semantic_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <ul class="formItem">         
    <%= f.input :username, :required => true, :label => "Your Username", :input_html => { :class => 'double' } %><br clear="all" />
    <p class="fieldExplanation">Your username is made public to other people on the site.</p>                       
  </ul> 
  <ul class="actions">      
    <%= f.commit_button("Save my profile and make a match >", :class => "submitForm") %>    
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

It's visually working - the form renders with a little asterisk to indicate that it understood :required => true - but when the page posts, it doesn't trigger validation with an error; instead, it simply moves on to the next page, as if it was successful.

I feel like I'm missing a simple setting somewhere to turn validation on, or perhaps I'm doing something wrong in my controller?

```
def update
 @user = User.find(params[:id])     
 respond_to do |format|
   if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])        
      format.html { redirect_to(match_user_path(@user), :notice => 'User was successfully updated.') }              
   else
     format.html { render :action => "edit" }        
   end
 end
end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm starting to think something else is broken - when I include     `<%= f.input :mySelectBox, as => :select, :collection => ["Thing one", "Thing two"] %>`    I get    **undefined local variable or method `as' for #<#<Class:0x837baf0>:0x837a368>**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have omitted the colon in the code you showed in your comment. It should be `:as` and that would explain some breakage.

In terms of validation, that is enforced in your model. You need something like:

```
validates :username, :presence => true
```

to make the code on the server side understand that without `username`, the model is invalid. Once you have all your server side validations in place, look at the validation_reflections gem if you want to zap those into your form quickly. You can read about it [on ASCIIcasts here](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/185-formtastic-part-2).

Answer (score 0):

Formtastic is *only* presentation of a form, so the validations need to be done server-side in the model. Formtastic will use those validations to infer if the input should be marked as required or not. The `:required` option in the DSL is really only there only to override this of for the rare occasions where you can't do what you need in model validations.